# Long legs squat foot position and posterior chain

Tags: weightlifting, squats

I've read a fair bit on this but just wanted to see what other opinions there were on this.

I'm 193cm (6'4") with an inside leg of 84cm, I've got longer than average leg to upper body ratio.

When squatting I've tried wide ( outside shoulder width, toes out ) but really find this tough on flexibility.

The most comfortable postion is a realatively narrow stance, ( I'm broad shouldered, you could call it a 'nipple stance' ) with quite a bit of external knee rotation ( if that makes sense, I 'spread the floor' as they say ).

Am I risking anything in this position? Possible knee trouble down the line?
Am I missing out on posterior chain development?

Comment: What kind of depth are you able to hit from that foot position with feet flat on the floor?

Comment: Usually just above parallel ( sometimes parallel at hip crease but not always ). I'm working on hip hinges.

Comment: I have long levers like you at the same height. So I understand your dilemna. I rarely back squat anymore. You might want to consider front squatting or doing away with barbell squatting altogether and try some Bulgarian split squats instead. They are a lot easier on the back and knees and they are very effective at building strength and hypertophy.

Comment: I guess that would be the wise thing. I was just hoping I could just go slow and steady with real strict form on the back squats.

Comment: When you talk about spreading the floor and having a lot of external rotation, are your feet pointed straight ahead or turned out? A few degrees turned out is fine, but if you turn your feet out a lot then you are likely collapsing your foot arch and putting yourself in a not so great position. When looking up videos from Kelley Starrett, mentioned below, you will probably find one where he talks about this.

Comment: Feet are at about 30 degrees outwards or so ( that was what I was taught when younger ).

Answer (score 1):

I would check out kelly starretts stuff on youtube (mwod). He is a technique and mobility guru.

It is possible for everyone(normal situation) to back squat without problems when you acquire the necessary mobility.

Comment: I'll have a look. Thing is I find the narrowish stance really comfortable, just curious if I'm setting myself up for a fall.